# Page doesn't respond to HREF until AJAX completes asynchronous fetch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an ajax request executing through the  XMLHttpRequest() object

My AJAX method is called in this format:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
$(document).ready(function () { LoadData(); });

function LoadData()
{
   var parameters = "DisplayData=true";
   var url = "default.aspx";
   Send(url, parameters, "DisplayData");
   CheckForAbort();
}

function Send(url, parameters, QueryType)
{
...
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-lencoded");
xmlhttp.send(parameters);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function (){...}
}
```

There is also a **timer** on the page which refreshes the data by making a new request through the Send(...) method in intervals of 15 seconds. Every .3 seconds and it calls an **Elipsis()** method that displays and "blinks" the "loading message" (if appropriate to be displayed) and checks for the abort.

```
var Color = "red";
function Elipsis() {
   if (ResponseMessage != "")
   {
    if (Color == "darkred") { Color = 'red'; } else { Color = 'darkred'; }
    $("#StatusResponse").css("display", "block");
    $("#StatusResponse").css("color", Color);
    CheckForAbort();
    }
}
function CheckForAbort()
{
    console.log("MenuActivted: " + MenuActivted);
    if (MenuActivted)
    {
        xmlhttp.abort();
        ResponseMessage = "Aborting Request";
        MenuActivted = false;
    }
}
```

But when the user clicks the menu bar which is an anchor tag with the HREF set to another page. The browser doesn't respond until the ajax request has completed it's fetch.

The HTML HREF is called the following way on an ASPX page:

```
<a href="<%#Eval("NavigateUrl")%>" onclick="AbortAjax();window.location='<% #Eval("NavigateUrl")%>';"><%#Eval("Text")%></a>
```

the Ajax Abort sets the flag that is checked in the **CheckForAbort()** method:

```
var MenuActivted = false;
function AbortAjax()
{
   MenuActivted = true;
   return false;
}
```

I am running IE 11 on Win 7. I have called an abort() method in another section of the code. which executes the xmlhttp.abort(). The response status and ready state respond (console output below) but the page still waits to respond to the HREF

**Console output:**

HTML1300: Navigation occurred.

File: ChangePassword.aspx

MenuActivted: true

ReadyState: 4

Status: 0

**Does anyone have a solution to this problem?**
[Updated **********]

I thought I had the solution but I didn't.

I commented out the **set** header but although it allowed my HREF to execute it was because the xhr was throwing an error and the fetch was terminating.

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
//xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(parameters);
```

Please read the entire post before responding.

Comment: *"Please read the entire post before responding."* A) That kind of comment is not useful. B) If it *were* useful, it would only be useful somewhere other than *at the bottom of the post*.

Comment: Recommend producing an [MCVE](/help/mcve) and posting it to the question. Also recommend reading through the question and fixing various issues (such as the image that isn't there). IE11 wouldn't normally behave this way, I wouldn't think, so making it easy for people to help you (e.g., giving them something they can copy and try) is in your best interest. Note that snippets are for **runnable** examples, you've made the mistake of using it just as a code block (it's a common mistake for newbies). For just code, use the `{}`, not the `<>`, button.

Comment: @TJThank you for your speedy response . Have you run into this problem? 

I apologize for offending you by requesting that people read the entire post before responding. But I have often had a problem where someone will post and answer that is a request for more information that is already contained in my response.  I will post some sample code per your request. so you can duplicate the problem. The long and the short of it is that the HREF doesn't respond until the AJAX fetch is complete.

Comment: Please post the whole code so we can see on which event the xhr is called exactly, and how does it relate to the abort function

Comment: @Szbolcs It is called in a function. Not on an event.  The xhr is created at page load with  as simple: var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

Comment: The method `AbortAjax` is not calling the `abort()` method.... The page navigation itself is causing the Ajax request to exit.

Comment: @epascarello. Thank you for the response. but I mentioned in the comments above the code that the flag is set in the method call and the timer is what calls the abort...

Comment: Timer does not execute same time as click.... Abort the call on click.... Also makes no sense why you have a link and you call window.location.href to do the same exact thing. Let the link be a link.

Comment: The abort is executing. Please see the console output. The redirect was just not happening. I think I have found the solution to my own problem below. Perhaps you can tell me why it was the solution.

Comment: Call abort, get rid of the window.location call.

Comment: I can't the menu click event is in the page master. The child page is the one that holds the xhr object. So if I called it on the menu click on any other page the object wouldn't exist and throw a JS error.

Comment: Why would you be calling in on another page??? Call `CheckForAbort` from the `AbortAjax` method.

Comment: Please read the above comment. The menu is in the Master page. The data is in the child page. I don't need to load the JS or the data on any other page. Also I've already stated that the execution of the abort is happening. the IIS and browser are just not responding to the HREF. The call is asynchronous (please see above) I think your suggestion is valid but doesn't solve the problem I'm experiencing. I believe the problem may either exist with IIS or IE itself.